# Count number of matching data in columns on the basis of primary key in two tables

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two tables with identical structure and somewhat identical data. As an example, let's consider the following tables.

Table Pri

```
id | name   | dept | rollno
1  | Mark   | A    | 4
2  | Michael| B    | 5
3  | Norman | C    | 6
4  | Paul   | D    | 7
5  | Robert | E    | 8
```

Table Sec

```
id | name   | dept | rollno
1  | Mark   | A    | 4
2  | Michael| B    | 5
3  | Norman | G    | 7
4  | Paul   | D    | 8
5  | Bradley| F    | 9
```

Now, on equating the 'id' between the two tables, I'd like to get a count of various column matches (name/dept/rollno), i.e., rows with 0 column matches, rows with 1 column match, rows with 2 column matches, and identical records (rows with all the matches).

For example, the result for the given data can be displayed as

```
column_matches| count
0             | 1
1             | 1
2             | 1
3             | 2
```

I'm on Oracle10g. Any ideas as to how to go about this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing this query, this should help, i hope:

```
SELECT ccols, COUNT(*)
  FROM(
       SELECT CASE WHEN p.name = s.name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN p.dept = s.dept THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
              CASE WHEN p.roolno = s.rollno THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ccols
         FROM prim p
         JOIN sec  s
           ON p.id = s.id
      )
 GROUP
    BY ccols;
```

Answer (score 1):

@DirkNM the solution you provided is indeed perfect for the specific situation @Ankur is facing.

However, a more generic way to do the same would be using a procedure.

Here is the script for the generic procedure to compare two table data (having exactly same structure).

```
/*
Author: Kasim Husaini
Creation Data: 18th Sept 2014
Description: Procedure to compare two tables and giving matching column count as a result set.
*/
Create PROCEDURE USP_COMPARE_TABLES(@P_PRI_TABLE VARCHAR(255)
    , @P_SEC_TABLE VARCHAR(255)
    , @P_PRIMARY_COL VARCHAR(255)
    ) AS
    BEGIN
        Declare @M_SQL VARCHAR(MAX)='';
        Declare @M_COL_COMPARE VARCHAR(MAX)='';
        Declare @M_SUB_QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)='';
        Declare @M_COMPARE_TEMPLATE VARCHAR(1000);
        Set @M_SQL='SELECT COL_COUNT, COUNT(1) MATCHES FROM ($X$) A GROUP BY COL_COUNT';

        SET @M_COMPARE_TEMPLATE = ' CASE WHEN P.$T$ = S.$T$ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END $N$';

        Select @M_COL_COMPARE=REPLACE(STUFF((Select '+'+REPLACE(@M_COMPARE_TEMPLATE,'$T$',C.NAME) FROM SYS.COLUMNS C 
        WHERE C.OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(@P_PRI_TABLE) Order BY C.NAME FOR Xml Path('')),1,1,'')
        ,'$N$',CHAR(13))

        SET @M_SUB_QUERY = 'SELECT (' + @M_COL_COMPARE + ') AS COL_COUNT FROM ' + @P_PRI_TABLE + ' P JOIN ' + @P_SEC_TABLE +' S ON P.$PC$=S.$PC$ ';

        SET @M_SUB_QUERY=REPLACE(@M_SUB_QUERY,'$PC$',@P_PRIMARY_COL);

        SET @M_SQL=REPLACE(@M_SQL,'$X$',@M_SUB_QUERY);
        PRINT @M_SQL;
        Exec(@M_SQL);
    END
```